# Пропадает звук в Linux после + и - что делать?

Tags: linux, аудио, kali-linux

Установил Linux. Решил обновиться через `sudo apt upgrade`, но после установки обновленя стал пропадать звук.... Точнее, когда я прибавляю или ументшаю, то он сначала работает ок, но после 3-4 нажатий просто идёт на спад и полностью вырубается и помогает только перезагрузка. `Alsamixer` тоже не помогает и переустановку его(тогда вообще звук пропадаетна совсем)

PS Также есть проблемы с подключением к Wi-Fi(постоянно обрывается), но это будет отдельным [вопросом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1220597/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-wi-fi-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-linux)

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать?

Answer (score 1):

Проблемы решил через `Synaptic` установив все обновления оттуда. Сразу звук пришёл в норму.