# Почему разрывается соединение Wi-Fi после обновления Linux?

Tags: linux, wifi, kali-linux

Установил Linux. Решил обновиться через `sudo apt upgrade`, но после установки обновленя стало разрываться соединение с WiFi. Ну, то есть раз в 5 минут стабильно отпадает инет. До обновления такого не было.

Что делать?

PS Также есть [вопрос про падение звука после обновления](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1220595/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BA-%D0%B2-linux-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)

Comment: хотите сказать, дистрибутив - Kali?

Comment: @VladislavTikhomirov, да

Comment: Драйвер не подходит к новому ядру

Comment: @eri, такс, и что с этим делать? -_-

Answer (score 0):

Проблемы решил через `Synaptic` установив все обновления оттуда. Сразу интернет перестал отваливаться.